# Different Bundle Identifier for different build configurations

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on an app right now and we're trying to get some testing done against the staging environment as well as the production environment.  Naturally, I've created "Stage" and "Prod" build configurations to switch between the two, but my client would like to have the two installed side by side so they could switch between the two environments easily.  I've been doing this so far by maintaining a branch of my code with a different bundle identifier and bundle display name, so they can be installed and tested side by side.  I'm beginning to wonder if there may be an easier way to do this, though.  Is there a way I could define a custom build setting, give it a value based on the build configuration, and then append that to the end of the bundle identifier?

Something like...

```
BUNDLE_SUFFIX
    TEST
    STAGE   
    PROD    ".PROD"
```

...and then set my Bundle Identifier to `com.blah.blah$(BUNDLE_SUFFIX)`.  Then all builds with the PROD config will automatically get the new bundle id and I won't have to synchronize branches all the time.  Is that kind of thing even possible?

Comment: One thing you could do is check the bundle ID in code and modify your apps behaviour based upon the bundle id. I have three versions of an app; development version, testing version and live version : each uses different web apis. So I check the bundle identifier at runtime to determine which URLs to use.

Comment: I also use different targets with different profiles, bundle identifiers and names, so I don't have to mess with any branching for this.

Comment: Is it only url that is changing in your stage and production build ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yep, you're on the right track. Here is a nice tutorial: http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-have-two-versions-of-the-same-app-on-your-device/

Comment: Nice! I'm no longer working on that project, but this looks like exactly the thing I needed back then.

Comment: That article worked well for me. The only thing I had to change was that if you're using an appiconset for your app icon, you can configure that in `Build Settings` -> `Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name` instead of replacing each icon file in the `plist`

Comment: That tutorial is helpful, but how do I specify which build configuration to build without making a separate scheme (which I don't want to do since it adds more manual overhead to the entire project)? Ideally I would have 3 configs: dev, staging, production - all would have different urls and bundle ids

Answer (score 50):

In **Xcode 7**:

this can be done easily using the packaging configuration in build setting

[image]

Comment: This is true. But, there is another bundle identifier placeholder in general tab of target settings. So, if you keep different bundle identifier for each configuration, how does it reflect in general pane?

Comment: Edit your scheme, and change `Run`'s `Build Configuration` to `Release` or something else, of which the default value is `Debug`. Then your `general` page will display `Release`'s configurations. @RashmiRanjanmallick

Comment: As well as this, I had to also set `Product Bundle Identifier` in Build Settings for each configuration. Otherwise the Provisioning Profile settings in the General tab would complain (Xcode 8).

Comment: This one should be accepted as the solution, I previously used the bundle id suffix approach, but this approach is more efficient and actually also allows you to have different provisioning profile for each environments