# Different Bundle Identifier for multiple schemas

Tags: ios, xcode

I've an iOS app with three targets (the app, the watch app and the extension) and it has two different sets of bundle identifiers for enterprise and store configuration (*com.enteprise.mybundleidentifier* and *com.mybundleidentifier*).

Is there a way to have different values for different schemas without duplicate three targets in six final targets?

May the Bundle Indentifier property use environment variables I can define as a Preprocessor Macros for each configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify bundle id for different schemas in target's Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Bundle Identifier

You can also use macros like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20151432