# How to use different bundle identifiers for beta testing and App Store Release

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I hope this isn't considered a duplicate. There's this question about using multiple bundle identifiers for your app:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20151432/3134192

The link in the accepted answer explains exactly what I want to do.
I want to have 3 different bundle identifiers: beta, debug, app store.
I want to name them like this:

```
App Store: {currentIdentifier}
Beta: {currentIdentifier}.beta
Debug: {currentIdentifier}.debug
```

**However**, I already uploaded my app to `App Store Connect` and I already submitted a build for beta testing in `TestFlight` (using `{currentIdentifier}` as bundle identifier). I don't know how to change that now. Is there a way to tell App Store Connect that I want to use the beta identifier for TestFlight and the other one for an App Store release?

---

*My only guess is this:*

I have to create another distribution profile for the beta bundle identifier, create a new AppID and a new app entry in App Store Connect. Then I'll have two versions of my app, the old one (with the currently active beta test and bundle identifier "`{currentIdentifier}`") and the new one (with the bundle identifier "`{currentIdentifier}.beta`"). Then I'd just have to start any new betas on the beta version and any app store releases on the other one.

Is this correct? I'm afraid that I'm breaking something when I try to create multiple AppIDs etc. for the same app.

Comment: Effectively the bundle id *is the app*. If you have a different bundle id it is a different app. It will be installed in a different sandbox with its own data on the device. You would need to create multiple entries in App Store Connect.